How to validate an empty field in wpf form using c# in a method?
I have this front end created, now i want to create back end logic. That will validate for this Compartment(combox-box) and purpose(combo-box). If truck is full(Compartment being selected and purpose is also selected for Full. Below is wpf ui, In summary this logic needs to apply before user clicks SaveTicket then must validate correctly. The issue this logic is not applied correctly and when debug its not hitting to that line.
<Label x:Name="lblPurpose" Content="Purpose:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" FontWeight="SemiBold" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxPurpose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Height="27"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblCompartment" Content="Compartment:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" FontWeight="SemiBold" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxCompartment" IsEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Height="26"/>

// back end class.cs
private void btnSaveReturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTicketNu.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a ticket");
                return;
            }
            //if(rdbtn1.Is checked){
            //update farm/ product
            //
            //}else
            //if(rdbtn2.Is checked){
            //update replacements
            //
            //}else

            if (chkFarmName.IsChecked == true)
            {
               // MessageBox.Show("Customer, Product AND Replacement Seals can ONLY be updated", "WARNING");
                var ticket = Managers.WeighbridgeTicketManager.GetWeighBridgeTicketPK(txtTicketNu.Text);
                ticket.Customer = cbxCustomer.Text;
                ticket.Product = cbxProduct.Text;
                ticket.ReplacementTopSeal = txtRTopSeal.Text;
                ticket.ReplacementBottomSeal = txtRBottomSeal.Text;

                Managers.WeighbridgeTicketManager.UpdateTripsheetCustomer(ticket);
                presenter.PopulateGrid(txtTripsheetNo.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Ticket " + TicketNumber + " updated successfully.", "Ticket Update");
                ClearFields();

            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReturnWeight.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter compartment weight");
                    return;
                }
                if (cbxPurpose.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a purpose");
                    return;
                }

                if (cbxCompartment.SelectedItem != null && cbxCompartment.SelectedItem.ToString() == "truck-empty")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRTopSeal.Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("TopSeal cannot be empty when truck is empty", "Validation Error");
                        txtRTopSeal.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                ReturnDelivery retDelivery = new ReturnDelivery();
                retDelivery.Comment = txtComment.Text;
                retDelivery.Customer = cbxCustomer.Text;
                retDelivery.Product = cbxProduct.Text;
                retDelivery.Productweight = Convert.ToInt32(txtReturnWeight.Text);
                retDelivery.Purpose = Convert.ToInt32(cbxPurpose.SelectedValue);
                retDelivery.Ticket = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketNu.Text);
                retDelivery.Trip = Convert.ToInt32(txtTripsheetNo.Text);
                var tickets = Managers.ReturnDeliveryManager.InsertReturnDelivery(retDelivery);
                ClearFields();
                MessageBox.Show("Return has been successfully saved");
               
            }
        }

// condition to check for fields
// Check if the compartment is empty and purpose is Leaving - Finished Product
     if (cbxCompartment.SelectedValue != null &&
            cbxPurpose.SelectedValue != null &&
            cbxCompartment.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower() == "truck-empty" &&
            cbxPurpose.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Leaving-Finished Product")
        {
            // Check if the TopSeal is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTopSeal.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TopSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving - Finished Product", "Validation Error");
                txtTopSeal.Focus();
                return;
            }

            // Check if the BottomSeal is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBottomSeal.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("BottomSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving - Finished Product", "Validation Error");
                txtBottomSeal.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }


You should validate every single field on load and on change. Each field validation result should be presented in the related control, for instance turning it to red. The "save" buttons should be disabled as long any of the field get a validation failure.

@MarioVernari what you mean, mind sharing that thought via code?

have a look here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/

Why are you not using 2-way databinding? This code looks like written for a UI framework which didn't know that data binding was a thing.

@TanveerBadar thats a good idea. Can you perhaps show me

"The issue this logic is not applied correctly and when debug its not hitting to that line." - A very cryptic way to describe an unexpected behavior. For example, what would be correct? And what line is not hit? Aside from that, you have some branched code. Have you debugged it to check the conditions? This could be the most obvious reason why any of the if-statements is not executed. If you still are not able to solve your problem, please provide more details so that a stranger can understand your problem.

In WPF the recommended way to validate properties is to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo (How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo). But to apply this you need to understand data binding (Data binding overview (WPF .NET)). I think if you want to write clean code you can't avoid data binding. It's really a fundamental WPF skill.

@BionicCode for an example if am validating an empty field for Topseal and Bottomseal without Compartment and Purpose from dropdown, It does fine, but the issue now the second statement to validate for an empty field while first if statement hits when debugging. Let me give an example to the topic will share code there for you to lookl
